# How do I crop faces with a neural network?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I am looking to build a facial recognition system and realized I could probably pump up accuracy by first cropping the faces. I know I can use a Haar Cascade classifier to do this but would prefer to use a deep learning approach, as that is my current area of focus. To do this do I simply create a CNN with inputs being an image and outputs being the X, Y, Width, Height? Or is there more to it? I have tried this approach with an Adam optimizer and around 600 pictures but results haven't been great. Any ideas on how to improve this?

Comment: You may want to use pixel-wise classification, fully convolutional networks. YOLO based approaches can be considered too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a fully convolution neural network trained for image segmentation. The architecture is typically convolutions followed by de-convolutional layers with out pooling.

[image]

The forward inference serves to extract information with convolutions. The de-convolutions serve to resize the tensors to the size of the inputs height and width. A fully connected layer then classifies *each* pixel from the input. [Deconvolutions demonstration.](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/0*NBKHZlXvqOg3R6_z.gif)

Unfortunately you need pixel wise labels to train a network to do this. You could look for a pretrained model that already segments faces from images or you could grind out hand labeling for a 1000 images and use transfer learning (there are online tools for doing this such as [Label box](https://github.com/Labelbox/Labelbox).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain why a simple DCNN that predicts bx, by, bwidth, bheight will not work for this problem?

Comment: Now that I think about it I think your idea is likely the best option, since your just cropping faces. DCNN typically work better when there are multiple objects in an image to segment but may be worth trying. Are you using a pretrained network? What do your training curves look like?

Comment: I am using VGG16 pre-trained on imagenet. Loss on training and validation are very similar but large as a whole. I assume VGG16 is powerful enough to fit the data so maybe I need to gather some more data. Thanks for the assistance!